# scaling three columns out of the dataset effects on the data

Tags: python, k-means, data-manipulation, scaling

I have a dataset I'm working on and I applied the k-means algorithm. Since some values in certain columns where huge, I was advised to take the logarithm of each value in those columns (specifically three of them).

My question is: why can we only logarithmize those 'problematic' columns? Does this not affect the integrity of the dataset? And if it does, how is it affected?

Comment: I would use zscore instead, but aside that, this is not really a python nor a programming question. Consider post it somewhere else. Check here, for example, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89809/is-it-important-to-scale-data-before-clustering